# Setting query to run as a stored procedure and email the results

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-mail, jobs

I have the following query:

```
select COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 1 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'New Connections'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 2 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Domestic Metered'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 3 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commercial Metered Low'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 4 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commerical Metered High'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 5 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Domestic Keypad'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 6 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Generator'
, COUNT(CASE WHEN New_accounttype = 7 THEN New_AccountType ELSE NULL END) as 'Commercial Keypad'
, COUNT(*) as 'Total Live'
from AccountExtensionBase as a
INNER JOIN CustomerAddressBase as b ON a.AccountId = b.ParentId
where New_AccountStage = 7
and AddressTypeCode is null
```

I want to set this up to automatically email the values on a daily basis. How can I convert this into a stored procedure and use. I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Configure Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver16)
2. Create a sql agent job to run below t-sql (you dont need a stored procedure for what you are asking, but below code can be easily converted into a stored procedure --> I will leave that up to you - hint: just look for [`Create procedure as ..`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16))

   ```
   ---- first check if there are any rows returned ... as we dont want to send empty email ....
   if exists (
           select 1
           from AccountExtensionBase as a
           inner join CustomerAddressBase as b on a.AccountId = b.ParentId
           where New_AccountStage = 7
               and AddressTypeCode is null
           )
   begin
       if object_id('#final_results') is not null
           drop table dbo.#final_results;

       select COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 1
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'New Connections'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 2
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Domestic Metered'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 3
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Commercial Metered Low'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 4
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Commerical Metered High'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 5
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Domestic Keypad'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 6
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Generator'
           ,COUNT(case 
                   when New_accounttype = 7
                       then New_AccountType
                   else null
                   end) as 'Commercial Keypad'
           ,COUNT(*) as 'Total Live'
       into dbo.#final_results -----<--- put results into temp table for easy processing ...........
       from AccountExtensionBase as a
       inner join CustomerAddressBase as b on a.AccountId = b.ParentId
       where New_AccountStage = 7
           and AddressTypeCode is null

       --- prepare for sending email ... since we have something to send ....
       declare @tableHTML nvarchar(MAX)
           ,@tableHTML2 nvarchar(MAX)
           ,@tableConnErr nvarchar(MAX)
           ,@tableDBConnErr nvarchar(MAX);
       declare @Mailsubject nvarchar(255)
           ,@mail_recipients nvarchar(255)

       set @mail_recipients = 'dbagroup@somecompany.com' --<-- CHANGE HERE 
       set @Mailsubject = 'Setting query to run as a stored procedure and email the results' --<-- CHANGE HERE 
       set @tableHTML = N'<H3><FONT SIZE="3" FACE="Tahoma">Below is the report as per [http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/104030/8783] : </FONT></H3>'
       set @tableHTML = @tableHTML + N'<table border="1">' + N'<FONT SIZE="2" FACE="Calibri">' + N'<tr><th align="center">New Connections</th>' + N'<th align="center">Domestic Metered</th>' + N'<th align="center">Commercial Metered Low</th>' + N'<th align="center">Commercial Metered High</th>' + N'<th align="center">Domestic Keypad</th>' + N'<th align="center">Generator</th>' + N'<th align="center">Commercial Keypad</th>' + N'<th align="center">Total Live</th>' + N'</tr>' + ISNULL(CAST((
                       select td = [New Connections],''
                           ,td = [Domestic Metered],''
                           ,td = [Commercial Metered Low],''
                           ,td = [Commercial Metered High],''
                           ,td = [Domestic Keypad] ,''
                           ,td = [Generator],''
                           ,td = [Commercial Keypad],''
                           ,td = [Total Live],''
                       from (
                           select *
                           from dbo.#final_results
                           ) A
                       order by 1 asc
                       for xml PATH('tr')
                           ,TYPE
                       ) as nvarchar(MAX)), '')
       set @tableHTML = @tableHTML + N'</FONT>' + N'</table>';
       set @tableHTML = @tableHTML + N'<H1><FONT SIZE="1" FACE="Verdana">Report By: @TheRockStarDBA ;Generated On: ' + convert(varchar, getdate()) + '</FONT></H1>'

       --print @tableHTML
       exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    @profile_name = 'YOUR MAIL PROFILE'----< CHANGE HERE !
                                      ,@recipients = @mail_recipients
                                       ,@subject = @Mailsubject
                                       ,@body = @tableHTML
                                       ,@body_format = 'HTML';
   end
   ```
3. [Add a schedule to the above job](https://web.archive.org/web/20160303143237/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/14/creating-a-regularly-scheduled-job.aspx).